# Normalizing Data and Insert Into SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I have what may be a stupid question but here it goes.

I have an ORDER_T table, a CUSTOMER_T table, and a ORDERLINE_T table.

I also have a set of data I need to normalize. Each record in this "bad data" has up to 3 items stored in it in attributes called Item1, Item2, and Item3. I thought I was normalizing it correctly by taking each item, separating it, and having it constitute it's own record was good. For example

```
ORDER_T

OrderID ItemID ItemDescription CustomerID
1        1001   Apple             100
1        1002   Grape             100
1        1003   Pear              100
```

**OrderID** is the **PK** and **CustomerID** is the **FK**. I realize thought as I tried to INSERT INTO my DB that it complained of multiple duplicate records via the PK. Duh--that makes sense. Now my question is:

I believe I am wrong but what would be the correct way to normalize data (to the third form) where each OrderID consists of multiple items? Is having attributes such as Item1, Item2, Item3, etc. "bad form" where it is not scalable and statically set like that? Am I overthinking it and should have simply left it alone?

I just believe I need some direction and I'll be good to go.

Comment: I'd go with an order detail table with order id, item id, and quantity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need next tables:

all unique customers

```
customers:
CustomerId (PK)
Name
```

all unique items

```
Items:
ItemId (PK)
ItemName
```

all unique orders:

```
Orders:
OrderId (PK)
CustomerID (FK)
OrderDate
```

and then you need many-to-many relationship table:

```
OrderItems:
OrderId (FK)
ItemId (FK)
count
primary key (OrderId, ItemId)
```

then you will be able to insert order (which can be empty), then add/remove items from this order via OrderItems table

Comment: I suggest you add the column CustomerID to Order table as a FK.

Comment: Ok I think I understand. Correct me if I am wrong: ORDER_T will serve to only store a record of an order being placed, with all appropriate data, whereas OrderItems will keep an accurate count of which items were ordered and how many? So when I need to query information such as how many Apples and pears were ordered for order 1001 I query both ORDER_T and OrderItems_T?